# Show valve on textbox based on combobox selection

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, data-binding, datacontext

I have two tables, binded by foreign key ProductID. Table one called as Product and table two called as sales. The ProductName i already binded with combobox in the sales windows. My question is how to show the ProductCost in a Textbox based on the selection on the ProductName in the combobox. Here the code i have to use to bind the combobox with ProductName:

```
  var Salespro = from s in contect.Products
                 select new { s.ProductID, s.ProductName };
        ComSalesProduct.ItemsSource = Salespro;
        ComSalesProduct.DisplayMemberPath = "ProductName";
        ComSalesProduct.SelectedValuePath = "ProductID";
```

Comment: It looks ok, but try adding .ToList, e.g. var Salespro = (from s in contect.Products
                 select new { s.ProductID, s.ProductName }).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

I assume cost in the products to add

```
  select new { s.ProductID, s.ProductName, s.Cost }; 


  <TextBox  text="{binding ElementName=CBsales path=SelectedItem.Cost}"
```

Another approach is to Use a ListView GridView and have Cost as another column.

Comment: @Blam.. i dont really understand the answer.Can you please explain more details?..

Comment: You can bind to an Element. With the edit my answer should make more sense.  Via the Path you can reference the SelectedItem.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx

Comment: @Blam.. what will be in CBsales?...im using "ProductCost" here as the entity of the product cost.

Comment: @Blam.. where must i put this code.. in the windows loaded or the sales adding form?..

Comment: Add Cost as a Public property in SalesPro.  For ElementName use the name of the combobox.  If you just search MSDN binding ElementName you will find a lot of material.